# Parsing sentences to create a chat bot

Tags: javascript, parsing, node.js

I am developing a chat bot with Node.Js. I am trying to find efficient way to parsing sentence.

> ```
> what do you think about humanity
> -> ba bla bla.
>
> what do you think about cats
> ->I love cats
> ```

Right now I am using the intersection technique, but I don't think it's efficient:

```js
var sentence = sentence.split(",")
var inters = intersectionOfArrays(sentence, ["what", "do", "you", "think", "about"])
if(inters.length >= 3) { //we have common words 
    keyword = extractionOfarrays(sentence,["what", "do", "you", "think", "about"]) // get question word (humanity, cats etc)
    if(keyword == "cats") 
       responseToServer("I love cats")
    if(keyword == "humanity") 
       responseToServer("bla bla bla")
}
```

Is this technique bad? I want to answer thousands of questions so I need to know what is the best method for doing some "AI" magic.

Answer (score 3):

From a personal standpoint, I think this method is fine. You might want to re-work it a little. I'd recommend creating an array with possible intersections, and looping through that array and checking user input against those. For example:

```
var intersections = [
    ["what", "do", "you", "think", "about"],
    ["what", "is", "your"],
    ...
];
```

Finally, I'd recommend having something that allows for multiple keywords, rather than one. In addition to this, you may not want to be checking the length of intersections based on a constant, in this case, three.

Anyways, if there's anything else that you want me to cover, just mention it in the comments, and I'll see what I can do.

Comment: Hey, thanks for reply. I searched and found AIML, it's more suitable for me. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AIML).

Answer (score 1):

A few things to point out:

> ```
> ["what", "do", "you", "think", "about"]
> ```

You should move this to an external array.

---

Rather than `==` matching responses in individual `if-else` loops: move the responses to a dictionary.

```
var responseDict = [
      "cats" : "I love cats"
    , "humanity": "bla bla bla"
]
```

Then, you can use the dictionary to build the response to fit into `responseToServer()`.

```
responseToServer(responseDict[keyword])
```